# Copy only cells with interior index color = 6

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy the cells of a column that contains the interior **color = 6** (vbyellow), and paste them into a new sheet and save this new leaf in **txt** format in **c:\code.txt**. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Eduardo the spirit of stackoverflow is that you ask a specific question and provide the code of what you tried so far with it so others can help fixing or suggest a different route. It isnt supposed to be used for asking broad questions in anticipation of a completely written program for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry first post. I'm not sure how the formatting works on this site yet. You would need to test the below. Add error handling and refactor accordingly. You also need to define the range columnRng somewhere on the sheet, in fact you might to change it to inputRange as it doesn't have to be column. As a side statement saving values highlighted by a certain colour to me sounds a bit like a can of worms, but you know your problem domain better than I do.

```
Option Explicit


Sub SaveValues()

Const colorLongVal As Long = 6
Dim rng As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim varToWriteToSht As Variant
Dim txtFileFullPath As String

txtFileFullPath = "f:\test.txt"
Set rng = Range("columnRng")
varToWriteToSht = GetValsByColour(rng, colorLongVal)

Set wks = WriteValsToNewSht(varToWriteToSht)
SaveWorkSheetAsTxtFile wks, txtFileFullPath

End Sub

Sub SaveWorkSheetAsTxtFile(ws As Worksheet, txtFileFullPath As String)

ws.SaveAs txtFileFullPath, xlTextMSDOS

End Sub


'Accepts 2D variant array. Creates a new worksheet and writes to the top right hand corner of that sheet

Public Function WriteValsToNewSht(varToWriteToSht As Variant) As Worksheet

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim resultRowsCnt As Long
Dim resultColsCnt As Long
Dim rngToWriteTo As Range

Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()
resultRowsCnt = UBound(varToWriteToSht, 1)
resultColsCnt = UBound(varToWriteToSht, 2)

If resultRowsCnt = 0 Then resultRowsCnt = 1
If resultColsCnt = 0 Then resultColsCnt = 1
Set rngToWriteTo = wks.Range("A1").Resize(resultRowsCnt, resultColsCnt)
rngToWriteTo.Value = varToWriteToSht

Set WriteValsToNewSht = wks

End Function

'Returns a variant array of the values that is writable directly to a range
Function GetValsByColour(rng As Range, interiorColourVal As Long) As Variant

Dim resultVar As Variant
Dim resultCol As Collection
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim val As Variant
Dim cell As Range

Set resultCol = New Collection

'You might want to not use a collection and redim the result array yourself
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = interiorColourVal Then
        resultCol.Add cell.Value
    End If
Next cell

ReDim resultVar(1 To resultCol.Count, 1 To 1)
For i = 1 To resultCol.Count
    resultVar(j + 1, 1) = resultCol.Item(i)
    j = j + 1
Next i

GetValsByColour = resultVar

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I would either use a filter or a loop through the cells.

Even though this is not complete, it should get you started...

```
  Sub Macro2()
      Columns("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
      Columns("A:A").Copy
      Workbooks.Add
      Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Code.txt", FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

  End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry this code gives a error: Method autofilter range class failed

Comment: ... I'm **guessing** you weren't in the correct sheet - Try first putting in `Sheets("MySheet").Select` - Otherwise, post your code because this worked for me

Comment: D'ont work, my code is the same code you used above

Comment: Are you in Excel 2003 or 2007+? The Filter for colors was only introduced in post Excel 2007... You would have to use a loop otherwise...